# Saltpetre in the Garage

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

My neighbour warned me that saltpetre (potassium (sodium) nitrate) is danger in the certain conditions. Is it possible that it can explode in my garage?

Comment: Darius, is this about salpeter crystals "growing" on the walls of your garage or about bags of fertilizer?

Answer (score 3):

Potassium and sodium nirate can be used to make black powder (gun powder), but they are not explosives by themselves. It is safe to store bags of salpetre in the garage.

If there's salpetre forming on the brickworks, I'd rather be concerned to keep the bags closed and away from that wall: sodium nitrate is rather hygroscopic and salpetre crystals on and between the bricks indicate that the wall is wet.